# Append unicode code points with their corresponding glyphs in a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x, unicode

I have a string in python

```
set = "U+06A4, U+06A7, U+06A8, U+06A9, U+06AF"
```

I want to find all the words starting with `U+` in this string and append these with their corresponding glyphs.

For example, say

```
word_found_in_string = 'U+064A'
```

I would like to replace it with

```
replace_with = 'U+064A chr(int(word_found_in_string[2:6],16))'
```

where `chr(int(word_found_in_string[2:6],16))` prints the corresponding glyph in my output file.

How can I use `re` module to do this for all the unicode code points in my string such that my resultant string has all the code points appended with their corresponding glyphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.sub` can take a function for the replacement.  Here I use a lambda function. It is called with the match object for each match of the regular expression.  `m.group(0)` is the whole match and `m.group(1)` is the parenthesized expression that matches the four hexadecimal digits.

```
import re
s = 'U+06A4, U+06A7, U+06A8, U+06A9, U+06AF'
s = re.sub(r'U\+([0-9A-F]{4})',lambda m: m.group(0)+' '+chr(int(m.group(1),16)),s)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
U+06A4 ڤ, U+06A7 ڧ, U+06A8 ڨ, U+06A9 ک, U+06AF گ
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. This is exactly what I wanted.